# PHP - Running a file on the browser (Including code giving error)

Tags: php, apache

I'm trying to run a file on the browser but it will not work.

e.g. when I type in the browser *http://localhost/Social_Network/login.php.*, I get the following error:

**Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Undefined class constant 'ATTR_ERRMODE_EXCEPTION' in C:\xampp\htdocs\social_network\login.php:3 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\social_network\login.php on line 3**

My code giving the response above is as follows:

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=social_network;charset=utf8', 
'root', '');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO:: ATTR_ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
?>
```

Any help is gratefully received.

Cheers

Bren

Comment: Well, without knowing what's on line three, there's not much we can do to help. Post your code. And not just that line, but in context, whatever is surrounding it.

Comment: On file `login.php` on line 3 you are using constant `ATTR_ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` but it's undefined. Without code we can't help

Comment: random guess its a typo for `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE` -- `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`

Comment: Thank you for comments, ive added my code giving the error if it helps?

Comment: Apologies, sorry to bother you - i have edited my question to include code now.  Thank you for your time

Comment: Thank you all for your responses, i've reattached the code giving the error. sorry to bother you all.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comments, its `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` not `PDO:: ATTR_ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`

Comment: Thanks again for comments above.  I tried this but it did not work.  Instead i googled a different channel how to set it up and the page work on localhost, without the PDO comments.  I'm unsure why, but i look like it works.  cheers